# How do game engines compile for multiple platforms?

Tags: c++, api, compilation, lua

So I am working on a engine/game with Lua scripting. What I was wondering was how I can create a tool to compile my game. How do engines like Unity create executable for multiple platforms? Is there some kind of API for compiling code?

For example:

```
Compiler->AddSource("Main.cpp");
Compiler->AddResource("Script.lua");
Compiler->CreateExecutable(COMPILE_WINDOWS_EIGHT, "AppName");
```

Does something like this exists? If not what else can I do to create the executables?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you using to compile your code at the moment?

Comment: No there's no runtime code emission/compilation available with standard c++.

Comment: Check out [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) and the [Clang API](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/index.html), they might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Can I use Clang to create a Windows 8 app package as well?

Answer (score 3):

To create executables on multiple platforms you need to use a different compiler on each platform or one that works on multiple ones such as g++, on windows its mingw.

A make-file is mostly used for larger programs to handle the commands that needs to be executed by the compiler. An easy tool to create crossplatform make-files, project-files etc is cmake (http://www.cmake.org/). Here you write a config files that is the same for all platforms and cmake can then generate the files required to build.